(Test Rail) If I delete test case (permanently) would it be displayed in activity summary?
Little question about Test Rail
If I delete test cases (permanently) would they be displayed in test activity summary?
Or will it look as if there was no activity?
I've tried google it already, but no results, unfortunately

The test case won't appear on the Activity Summary report.
However, if you have enabled auditing to High (Site Settings > Configuration > Audit level), for example, then the creation and deletion events will appear as log entries.

